# How to add/substract two 'hours' as integers?

Tags: c++, time

I know that maybe its a silly question but I have some troubles with it, I'm ashamed but I really don't know, how to make it. I want to add and subtract two 'hours' given as integers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // should be: 21:59:2
    int rH, rM, rS;

    int h1 = 12, m1 = 34, s1 = 56;
    int h2 = 9, m2 = 24, s2 = 6;

    if(h1 + h2 >= 24)
    {
        rH = abs(h2 + h1);
        m1 += 60;

        if(m1 + m2 >= 60)
        {
            rH = (m2 - m1);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        rH = h1 + h2;
    }

    cout << rH << " " << rM << " " << rS << " " << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Tried the above but I don't know how to do it further. I cant use any `date-time` objects.

EDIT

subtraction, I don't know where the error is but it calculates wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rH, rM, rS;
    int h1 = 12, m1 = 25, s1 = 29, h2 = 11, m2 = 12, s2 = 1;
    int sum1, sum2, sum;

    sum1 = (h1)*3600 + (m1)*60 + s1;
    sum2 = (h2)*3600 + (m2)*60 + s2;

    if(sum1 > sum2)
        sum = sum1-sum2;
    else
        sum = sum2-sum1;

    rS = sum %60;
    sum = sum/60;
    rM = sum % 60;
    rH = sum/60;

    std::cout << rH << " " << rM << " " << rS << " " << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: start from seconds... and keep the rest above 60 for minutes, and go on and on

Comment: it looks like you need to add two *times* rather than *hours*?

Comment: @Philipp - it's C++, not Java...

Comment: Most C applications treat times as UNIX timestamps (an integer which represents seconds since January 1st 1970). The type used for this is time_t. Using a single integer has the advantage that you can easily add and subtract them. There are also functions which convert it to a human-readable date: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/

Comment: @Philipp Just for the record, `time_t` does _not_ have to be an integral type, neither in C nor in Unix.  (I've never heard of an implementation where `time_t` isn't integral.  But a lot of code I'm familiar with keeps times in a `double`, as a fraction of a day.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// addition
int rH=0, rM=0, rS=0; 

rS = s1+s2;
if (rS>60)
{
    rM++;
    rS %= 60;
}

rM += m1+m2;
if (rM>60)
{
    rH++;
    rM %= 60;
}

rH += h1+h2;
if (rH>24)
{
    // 1 day more, who cares
    rH %= 24;
}

cout << rH << " " << rM << " " << rS << " " << "\n";
```

---

// substraction

int rH = 0, rM = 0, rS = 0;
    int h1 = 12, m1 = 25, s1 = 29, h2 = 11, m2 = 12, s2 = 1;

```
rS = s1 - s2;
if (rS<0)
{
    rM--;
    rS += 60;
}

rM += m1 - m2;
if (rM<0)
{
    rH--;
    rM += 60;
}

rH += h1 - h2;
if (rH<0)
{
    // Error occurred ...
}

cout << rH << " " << rM << " " << rS << " " << "\n";
```

Comment: thank you so much! How about substracion, maybe can you write it?

Comment: Ok, I will try, hold on a sec

Comment: Happy programming, you'll get it!

Comment: You're lacking some security measures. If seconds or minutes or hours contain invalid values on the start, this code may produce invalid results (add 99 seconds to 99 seconds, for instance).

Comment: @duDE: could you please take a look at my substraction? It doesnt work properly and I dont know wheres an error :(

Comment: @Brian: on the first glance it seems to be all right - good job! I have edited my answer added subtraction the same way like addition above - careful, not compiled just written! HTH

Answer (score 2):

Why not

```
int t1 = ((h1 * 60) + m1) * 60 + s1;
int t2 = ((h2 * 60) + m2) * 60 + s2;
int tdiff = t1 - t2;
if (tdiff < 0) { tdiff += 24 * 60 * 60;
```

Then use modular aritmetic and division to get the hours etc e.g.

```
int tdiffs = tdiff % 60;
tdiff  = tdiff / 60;
int tdiffm = tdiff % 60;
tdiff h = tdiff / 60;
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach could be (assuming you wanted to add the two *times* rather than simply the hour components) would be to:

1. Convert the first time to total seconds (use the appropriate multiplier for each component, hours/minutes and seconds.)
2. Convert the second time the same way
3. Now add/subtract as necessary - this will give you a new time in seconds.
4. If the new time is less tan 0, add a day's worth of seconds to it, if the new time is more than a day's worth of seconds, subtract
5. The resulting value in seconds can then be decomposed to hours minutes and seconds via a reverse of what you did in step 1 (hint you'll need the modulo operator...)

EDIT: Oh why do I bother with trying to provide ideas rather than code, when folk (who clearly should know better) simply provide the code.... :(

Answer (score 0):

you could either work in the lowest resolution for the calculation (seconds in you example) as Ed Heal shows.

or add starting with the Lest Significant Value and add the carry to the next value like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // should be: 21:59:2
    int rH(0), rM(0), rS(0);

    int h1 = 12, m1 = 34, s1 = 56;
    int h2 = 9, m2 = 24, s2 = 6;

    rS = s1 + s2;
    while (rS >= 60)
    {
        rS -= 60;
        rM++;
    }

    rM += m1 + m2;
    while (rM >= 60)
    {
        rM -= 60;
        rH++;
    }

    rH += h1 + h2;
    while (rH >= 24)
    {
        rS -= 24;
    }

    cout << rH << " " << rM << " " << rS << " " << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```